# How to align console panel to right in codesandbox?

Tags: interface, menu, alignment, panel, codesandbox

I'd like to align the browser/test/console panel to the right side of the js panel.

First tried to drag them, but it didn't work.

Is there any way?

[image]

Answer (score 27):

View > Editor Layout > Flip Full Layout

[image: Screenshot of commands]

Comment: Appreciate the answer. This is one of the worst UX designs I've ever seen. The option should be where the change is. But short of that... "flip full layout" means nothing to a user to tell them it makes it horizontal vs vertical. Wow.

Comment: yea, it's a horrible discoverability

Answer (score 1):

`Moritz W`'s solution seems to do the trick but only *temporarily*. I noticed that when I close and re-open the sandbox - the location of the browser window goes back to it *original **bottom** location*.

One way to deal with this is to create a [template](https://codesandbox.io/docs/templates) with the browser window on the right.

Creating a template however does not mitigate the situation when you are forking someone else's code. To persist the location of the browser window you must change the settings like this: `File` / `Preferences` / `CodeSandbox Settings` > `Open VSCode Settings` > `Workbench` / `Editor Management` / `Open Side By Side Direction` > `right`

If you are confused - here is an ***imgur*** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttbh8.jpg) to show you how to get there.

PSA - I am not entirely confident in this solution - please let me know in the comments if this worked for you.

Comment: Hm that didn't seem to work for me. Reopening the sandbox with "Side by Side Direction" set to "right" didn't keep the browser window on the right. What's strange is that while the sandbox is loading, the browser window is shown on the right, then once loading is complete, it moves to the bottom. I was testing with a new React sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

In a mac or a macbook you can do this, at least in 2023

[image]